# How to forward host headers to the origin in CloudFront UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront

An excerpt from this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-cloudfront-to-forward-headers/) part of the Amazon knowledge center:

> For **Cache Based on Selected Request Headers**, choose **Whitelist**.

Unfortunately, these buttons do not exist anymore in the latest [web interface](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/home?region=eu-west-2#):

[image: Cloudfront web interface settins]

How can I forward the host headers to the origin?

Answer (score 1):

This is done via the cache policy.

Previously this was done via the cache policy, however AWS has recently announced an Origin Request Policy.

By using this you can select the headers that are forwarded to the Origin (in your case the 'Host Header').

Take a look at the [Creating origin request policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-origin-requests.html#origin-request-create-origin-request-policy) documentation to use the steps of how to create one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Perhaps you meant to say something else after "previously this was done with ..."?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this old way, you can choose `Use legacy cache settings` for the option `Cache and origin request settings`.

`Cache Based on Selected Request Headers` Option is the next line will give you to Whitelist header.

Note : Amazon says - `We recommend using a cache policy and origin request policy to control the cache key and origin requests.`  instead of this Legacy way